# C# Factory Async Socket ERROR "On host disconnect"

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, factory

```
 async Task ReceiveFromClient()
        {
            if (this.m_ClientSocket.Connected == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var asyncResult = this.m_ClientSocket.BeginReceive(m_LocalBuffer, 0, m_LocalBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, null, null);
        /* Exception here */ int bytesReceived = await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(asyncResult, _ => this.m_ClientSocket.EndReceive(asyncResult)); /* This is the line with Exception */

                    if (bytesReceived != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Packets received");
                        m_LocalSecurity.Recv(m_LocalBuffer, 0, bytesReceived);

                        List<Packet> ReceivedPackets = m_LocalSecurity.TransferIncoming();
                        if (ReceivedPackets != null)
                        {
                            foreach (Packet _pck in ReceivedPackets)
                            {
                                new PacketHandler.PacketFromClientHandler(this, _pck, null);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.DisconnectModuleSocket();
                        this.m_delDisconnect.Invoke(ref m_ClientSocket);
                        return;
                    }

                    await Task.Factory.StartNew(this.ReceiveFromClient);

                }
                catch (AggregateException ae)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ae);
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message} ({ex.GetType()})");
                }

                //Exceptions: ArgumentNullException, SocketException, ObjectDisposedException, ArgumentOutOfRangeException
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    this.DisconnectModuleSocket();
                    this.m_delDisconnect.Invoke(ref m_ClientSocket);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here you can see my code its an Async TCP Socket where i read Packets from Client to Server everything working fine but when the User disconnect from the Socket the Commented line give me an Exception. I've searched a lot of hours but i didn't find an answer for my Problem.

I've already tryed to capture the Exception but without any success.

I need something that Stop the Task and close the Connection when user drops the connection.

Error that Visual Studio 2016 gives me is:

> Exception Type: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   ErrorCode: 10054
>   Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Thank you for Help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help i got from qqdev <3 its easy just change this line:

```
int bytesReceived = await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(asyncResult, _ => this.m_ClientSocket.EndReceive(asyncResult));
```

To this one:

```
int bytesReceived = await Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(asyncResult, _ => {try { return this.m_ClientSocket.EndReceive(asyncResult); } catch(Exception ex) {} return 0; } );
```